# Is there any way to pass login information to read a website in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, webrequest

i want to read a website in C# using this:

```
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.myurl.com/test.aspx");
        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
        string strResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

the issue is that they now have authentication on the page so i get the login prompt when i go to the website and have to type in user name and login.

my code now returns the error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

i tried adding this:

```
myWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[username]", "[pwd]");
```

and this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

but still got the same error:

Is there anyway to pass those credentials in the WebRequest code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the website is using HTTP basic authentication (a browser-generated login dialog), you can set the `HttpWebRequest`'s `Credentials` property to a `NetworkCredential` instance.

If the website uses forms authentication (an HTML-based login form; this is more common), you'll need to make a separate request to login to the site and share a `CookieContainer` across the requests to preserve the login.
You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to see what the login request should look like.

Comment: see updated question . .doesn't seem to work.   can you explain how i would use fiddler to determine what is expected ??

Comment: @ooo: Log on to the website with Fiddler running and look at the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can pass login information (when authentication "consists of either Basic Authentication (which is application driven prompting for an operating system account usually) or NTLM (integrated file security)"):

```
myWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
```

A deeper insight here:

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebrequest/dotnetwebrequest.htm

Comment: @ooo - Have you read the article? Perhaps there is more info related. I suppose it is not "https", if so: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/48909.aspx to accept all certificates.

Comment: definately not https - i updated the question. i have added the acceptsall policy but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @ooo - perhaps there is a proxy in between. In the article I mention they talk about this. To know this, in fiddler > inspectors > headers > auth, if there is nothing in between it will say " NO Proxy-Authenticate Header is present. WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Basic realm="THEURLYOUWANT.es"